# Does the GitHub Container Registry provide something like a Deploy Key?

Tags: deployment, github, authentication, ghcr

Currently I push to the [GitHub Container Registry (GHCR)](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) with my Personal Access Token.

Is there a method to deploy a **PRIVATE** project "GitHub Container Registry" such that a token will only have access to specified images rather than all of my private images? It seems they have funcitonality that will do this called ["Deploy Key" but that it only works for the Git Repository itself, not artifact repositories (like GHCR)](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys).

I don't see anything documented under

- [Working with the Container registry: Pulling container images](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#pulling-container-images)
- [Working with the Container registry: Authenticating to the Container registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry)

---

At work we use [GitLab and I know it does have per-project Deploy Keys for the container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-with-the-container-registry)

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you find a solution? But it looks like there is just no way to do proper authentication that does not depend on a personal GitHub account.

Comment: Same issue here, deploy keys are not supported on GHCR. The only solution seems to be to use a PAT with a full Docker login flow, or by writing a Docker registry "proxy" that removes the authentication or moves it to e.g. the URL schema.